# Are these SQL queries equivalent (natural join)?

Tags: sql

Given these tables:

- participated (license_number, car_regnum, report_number, damage_amount)
- car (car_regnum, model, year)
- accident (report_number, date, location)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.report_number), c.model
FROM accident as a, car as c, participated as p
GROUP BY c.model
HAVING a.report_number= p.report_number and c.car_regnum=p.car_regnum  
and a.date>= '2016-01-01'
ORDER BY DESC
```

And:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT accident.report_number), model
FROM accident NATURAL JOIN participated NATURAL JOIN car 
WHERE date >= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY model;
ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: Your first query uses fairly bizarre syntax, and would only work on MySQL (I think).  But, if your question is are the joins being made using the same columns, the answer is seems to be yes.  Do you get the same result set from both queries?

Comment: Using `HAVING` where `WHERE` should be is certainly fairly bizarre, and I would have expected the query not to even work (using non-grouped columns in `HAVING`).

Comment: @Amadan MySQL (and maybe SQLite) has overloaded `HAVING` to behave like `WHERE`.  One (possibly) legitimate benefit of this is that MySQL's overloaded `HAVING` can use an alias defined in the select clause, whereas `WHERE` cannot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you refering to this? "If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. [...] In this case, the server is **free to choose any value from each group**, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is **probably not what you want**. " - emphasis mine; it should mean the queries are _not_ equivalent (not because of `NATURAL JOIN` tho)

Comment: @Amadan No, you're citing the wrong thing really.  You might need `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode to use the alias in `HAVING`, but the functional dependency concern isn't really a problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How so? Without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, docs say MySQL follows ANSI and rejects queries involving non-functionally-dependent non-grouped columns. Not sure what it means for other tables than `c`, but at least `c.car_regnum` fits the bill: not functionally dependent on `c.model`, and yet not mentioned in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Using overloaded `HAVING` and selecting non functional columns are two different things.  They are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you point at where in docs this overload is described? I was reading [MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and I couldn't see anything like what you were describing.

Comment: I am giving up.

Comment: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN syntax. Specify the JOIN conditions!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not want you to give up. I wanted to read about it to learn things I did not before. If you read it as "I couldn't find it in docs so you're wrong"... that's not what I intended.

Comment: @Amadan No...all I was trying to say is that MySQL's overloaded `HAVING` and allowing bad `GROUP BY` queries are two different things.  Maybe the same flag controls both.  Neither are part of ANSI SQL, and neither would work on most RDBMS :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that they perform the same logic and so should be equivalent.

I wouldn't consider using the first one though - comma joins are too easy to mess up, and explicit join syntax has been part of the standard for over a quarter of a century.

The second one I would be happy with, but many people have a "distaste" for `NATURAL JOIN`. `NATURAL JOIN` is great if you're working within a disciplined team where each column name is used to stand for exactly one thing, but in many organisations, names (especially some common ones like `Description`) may be reused across tables and shouldn't be part of the join conditions.

So most people (that I know of) would probably prefer this instead:

```
SELECT
  model,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.report_number)
FROM
  accident a
    INNER JOIN
  participated p
    ON
      a.report_number = p.report_number
    INNER JOIN
  car c
    ON
      p.car_regnum = c.car_regnum
WHERE
  date >= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY
  model;
```

Comment: I agree with your SELECT but disagree that the poster's 2 queries are the same.Only MySQL could turn out any kind of result from that mess.  It would be best to assume not equal and just do it properly using standard SQL like you have.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - yes, there's an implicit "if your database system even accepts query one and runs it" in there somewhere :-) `NATURAL JOIN` is of course in the standard so query two does seem well formed for any fully standards conforming DB, though as I say, I'm aware that it's viewed with distaste by many.

Comment: Yeah I can't believe there was nothing better for the standards committee to do than work out `NATURAL JOIN`.  Ugh!  Things would be very different if I ruled the world....:)

Comment: Even though generally against `NATURAL JOIN`, there's places when it's nice and safe and improves readability. I used `NATURAL JOIN` only in one circumstance: when joining with a subquery that generates exactly one column: e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT generate_series(?, ?, INTERVAL '5 min') AS sampled_at) times NATURAL LEFT JOIN samples`.

Comment: It is not a "distaste".  `Natural join`s ignore properly declared foreign key relationships.  Hence, they are not "natural".  Worse, they make queries very difficult to debug.  They simply should not be used.